# Protocol "smb" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

My curl version:

```
Array
(
    [version_number] => 470785
    [age] => 3
    [features] => 524809
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.47.1
    [host] => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    [ssl_version] => 
    [libz_version] => 1.2.8
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => gopher
            [4] => http
            [5] => imap
            [6] => pop3
            [7] => rtsp
            [8] => smtp
            [9] => telnet
            [10] => tftp
        )

)
```

how can I enable this protocol smb ?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SMB); //not working
```

Answer (score 4):

libcurl supports SMB since [7.40.0](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_40_0).

Make sure you install a libcurl version where the protocol wasn't disabled. The supported protocols list you show indicates you have a limited set. An ordinary libcurl installed from a popular Linux distro will support many more protocols, including the TLS based ones that are missing in your protocol list (HTTPS, FTPS, POP3S, IMAPS etc)

Also make sure that you build your libcurl (if you build it yourself) with a TLS library, as the SMB code needs NTLM support and the NTLM code only works using some crypto functions from one of the TLS libraries libcurl supports.

When that is done, you don't need to use `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` and `CURLPROTO_SMB` at all, as then libcurl will support it out of the box by default.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 7.40.0 - January 8 2015

Changes:

```
http_digest: Added support for Windows SSPI based authentication
version info: Added Kerberos V5 to the supported features
Makefile: Added VC targets for WinIDN
config-win32: Introduce build targets for VS2012+
SSL: Add PEM format support for public key pinning
smtp: Added support for the conversion of Unix newlines during mail send
smb: Added initial support for the SMB/CIFS protocol
Added support for HTTP over unix domain sockets, via CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH and --unix-socket
sasl: Added support for GSS-API based Kerberos V5 authentication
```

File read not working or i dont know how to use

Answer (score 0):

ok i i installed 7.43 libcurl and
Array
(
    [version_number] => 469760
    [age] => 3
    [features] => 968605
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.43.0
    [host] => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.0.2d
    [libz_version] => 1.2.8
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => ftps
            [4] => gopher
            [5] => http
            [6] => https
            [7] => imap
            [8] => imaps
            [9] => ldap
            [10] => ldaps
            [11] => pop3
            [12] => pop3s
            [13] => rtmp
            [14] => rtsp
            [15] => smb
            [16] => smbs
            [17] => smtp
            [18] => smtps
            [19] => telnet
            [20] => tftp
        )

)

i can get file content from smb but how to get catalog list files ?